# Streaming the file with different name nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using lambda function to read a file and stream it using a different name written in nodejs

```
http.get('https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png', res=> res.pipe(fs.createReadStream('data.png')));

request('https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data.png'))
```

It gives me following error: 
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'data.png'
at Error (native)

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused due to AWS Lambda environment. By default, Lambda runs in the `/var/task` directory. But it is read-only. You have an ephemeral storage of 512 MB mounted under `/tmp` which is writable!. This can be found in the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

[image]

This means you have to modify your code to write file into `/tmp` like that:

```
http.get('https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png', res=> res.pipe(fs.createReadStream('/tmp/data.png')));

request('https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/data.png'))
```